# Using the same option multiple times in Python's argparse

Tags: python, argparse, multiple-arguments

I'm trying to write a script that accepts multiple input sources and does something to each one. Something like this

```
./my_script.py \
    -i input1_url input1_name input1_other_var \
    -i input2_url input2_name input2_other_var \
    -i input3_url input3_name
# notice inputX_other_var is optional
```

But I can't quite figure out how to do this using `argparse`. It seems that it's set up so that each option flag can only be used once. I know how to associate multiple arguments with a single option (`nargs='*'` or `nargs='+'`), but that still won't let me use the `-i` flag multiple times. How do I go about accomplishing this?

Just to be clear, what I would like in the end is a list of lists of strings. So

```
[["input1_url", "input1_name", "input1_other"],
 ["input2_url", "input2_name", "input2_other"],
 ["input3_url", "input3_name"]]
```

Comment: So why not associate the multiple input source arguments with that single option?

Comment: Because each of the multiple input sources also need to have multiple string arguments. I'd like to have to use the -i flag for each one of the inputs, and each input would contain all the strings between successive -i flags. I want it to work like ffmpeg where you specify inputs with -i

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Here's a parser that handles a repeated 2 argument optional - with names defined in the `metavar`:

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i','--input',action='append',nargs=2,
    metavar=('url','name'),help='help:')

In [295]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipython2.7 [-h] [-i url name]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i url name, --input url name
                        help:

In [296]: parser.parse_args('-i one two -i three four'.split())
Out[296]: Namespace(input=[['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four']])
```

This does not handle the `2 or 3 argument` case (though I wrote a patch some time ago for a Python bug/issue that would handle such a range).

How about a separate argument definition with `nargs=3` and `metavar=('url','name','other')`?

The tuple `metavar` can also be used with `nargs='+'` and `nargs='*'`; the 2 strings are used as `[-u A [B ...]]` or  `[-u [A [B ...]]]`.

Answer (score 116):

This is simple; just add both `action='append'` and `nargs='*'` (or `'+'`).

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', action='append', nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then when you run it, you get

```
In [32]: run test.py -i input1_url input1_name input1_other_var -i input2_url i
...: nput2_name input2_other_var -i input3_url input3_name

In [33]: args.i
Out[33]:
[['input1_url', 'input1_name', 'input1_other_var'],
 ['input2_url', 'input2_name', 'input2_other_var'],
 ['input3_url', 'input3_name']]
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed! :D

Side note: a possible default needs to be type list / array, or Argparse will fail

Comment: Note that you can put more than three arguments for -i with this: you ought to check that and raise an error if the user adds more than 3.

Answer (score 34):

`-i` should be configured to accept 3 arguments and to use the `append` action.

```
>>> p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> p.add_argument("-i", nargs=3, action='append')
_AppendAction(...)
>>> p.parse_args("-i a b c -i d e f -i g h i".split())
Namespace(i=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']])
```

To handle an optional value, you might try using a simple custom type. In this case, the argument to `-i` is a single comma-delimited string, with the number of splits limited to 2. You would need to post-process the values to ensure there are at least two values specified.

```
>>> p.add_argument("-i", type=lambda x: x.split(",", 2), action='append')
>>> print p.parse_args("-i a,b,c -i d,e -i g,h,i,j".split())
Namespace(i=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['g', 'h', 'i,j']])
```

For more control, define a custom action. This one extends the built-in `_AppendAction` (used by `action='append'`), but just does some range checking on the number of arguments given to `-i`.

```
class TwoOrThree(argparse._AppendAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        if not (2 <= len(values) <= 3):
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, "%s takes 2 or 3 values, %d given" % (option_string, len(values)))
        super(TwoOrThree, self).__call__(parser, namespace, values, option_string)

p.add_argument("-i", nargs='+', action=TwoOrThree)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I had different issue, as append appends to the given default value not replace it and I needed a flat list. So I used the abstract base class `Action`.

Answer (score 18):

Adding with Other in this Thread.

If you use `action='append'` in `add_argument()` then you will get arguments in list(s) within a list every time you add the option.

As you liked:

```py
[
   ["input1_url", "input1_name", "input1_other"],
   ["input2_url", "input2_name", "input2_other"],
   ["input3_url", "input3_name"]
]
```

But if anyone wants those arguments in the same `list[]`, then use `action='extend'` instead of  `action='append'` in your code. This will give you those arguments in a single list.

```py
[
  "input1_url", 
  "input1_name", 
  "input1_other", 
  "input2_url", 
  "input2_name", 
  "input2_other", 
  "input3_url", 
  "input3_name"
]
```

Comment: your answer lies at the bottom, but I was looking exactly for this `extend` bit :) thanks!

Comment: yes, exactly that answer