# Python: Argparse with list of lists

Tags: python, argparse

Minimum verifiable example:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='...')
parser.add_argument('-f','--file', type=str, nargs='+', help='file list')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.sparse[:])
```

And the idea is that I call this as:

```
python my_script.py -f f1 f2 f3 -f some_other_file1 some_other_file2 ...
```

And the output would be:

```
[ [ f1 f2 f3 ] [ some_other_file1 some_other_file2 ] ]
```

However, in this case, all that is printed out is:

```
 [ some_other_file1 some_other_file2 ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the same option multiple times in Python's argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36166225/using-the-same-option-multiple-times-in-pythons-argparse)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`action='append'` may be what you want:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='...')
parser.add_argument('-f','--file', type=str, nargs='+', action='append', 
help='file list')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.file)
```

will give

```
$ python my_script.py -f 1 2 3 -f 4 5
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5']]
```